# Center peek wallpaper in activity without stretching

Tags: android, android-activity, background, wallpaper

I'm developing an alternative `home application` which fits on one screen.
Currently I have one activity ,which has the height and width of the phone screen,in which I try to set default wallpaper as background.

I use this code to do this:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(peekWallpaper());
```

The problem is that it stretch the wallpaper to make it fit in one screen, so my wallpaper becomes completely flattened.

I found a workaround to avoid this, I extends drawable class and overide the method setBounds in order to avoid the stretching. But by doing this, I only see the left top corner of my wallpaper. So I would like to center it.

How can I do that ? Am I on the right way to do it ?

I have seen some methods in WallpaperManager class to move wallpaper :

```
setWallpaperOffsetSteps(float xStep, float yStep)
```

and

```
setWallpaperOffsets (IBinder windowToken, float xOffset, float yOffset)
```

But I don't find any sample of code on how to use `IBinder` parameters, can it be usefull on my case ?

Thx in advance.